# When to implement templates using constraints in C++20

Tags: c++, templates, constraints, c++20, c++-concepts

I try to find out when I should use C++20 template constraints.

Currently I use constrains only to disambiguate template overloads.

However there are many more templates that are not overloaded. Virtually all of them have implicit expectations regarding features of the template type(s).

As an example lets assume a function template that implicitly expects a container type and accesses that container by calling a `T::size()` method and using the `T::operator[]` operator.
Normally I get a compile error if the passed type doesn't provide the `T::size()` method and/or the `T::operator[]`. Still I could add explicit constraints to express the required features.

In which cases could it be fatal to rely on implicit compilation errors instead of explicit constraints? What are the advantages of explicit constrains over implicit requirements other than using the constraints as a part of the documentation?

Comment: Concept requires generally more constraints on type that needed/used in implementation, Using a `RandomAccessContainer<T>` constraint would also force presence of `begin`/`end`, and not just indexing by `[]` and `size` (so implementers are free to change code without breaking code relying on their implicit requirements). That would force you to have your types more complete. (as lot of custom type implement `operator <` but not `operator >`).

Comment: For those who closed the issue: I have no idea how to ask this question more focused other than by not asking the questions at all. Please edit the question in the way you had in mind when closing the question.

Comment: Unfortunatly, your question could be only be answered by experiment sharing. That is too broad for poeple, as is abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the tendency in C++ code with concept, is to have either overload constrained function that are meant to be found by argument dependent name look-up, or functor with constrained call operator.

No not constrained template free function (*). And the moral could end-up in no free function that are not supposed to be overloaded.

All template functions that are not constrained and not supposed to be overloaded are better replaced by functor objects. I see 3 reasons for that:

1. The addition of constraints to a free function that is not supposed to be overloaded is counter-productive: the addition of the constraints actually open more space to unwanted overloads.
2. On the other hand, function call operator cannot be overloaded in client code.
3. Once declared in a scope a functor object disable argument dependent name look up.

Finally, the range library go even further. For every function that is supposed to be overloaded by clients, the library declares and uses functor objects that checks that the overload that will be called fulfill some constraint that all overloads are supposed to satisfy. For example `std::range::begin`. In the library those functors are called *customization point object*. This is probably the safest approach, but the implementation of this is quite a bit lengthy.

(*) see Davis Herring comment just bellow for special case were functor object cannot be an option.

Comment: Template arguments that can be deduced *or* specified is another reason, besides overloading/ADL, to have a function and not a function object (sometimes).

Comment: @DavisHerring I add an asterix for that.